How to load GeoJSON data using ArcGIS maps SDK for Kotlin
I am using ArcGIS map SDK for Kotlin, but I have a problem while loading a GeoJSON string into the map.
Here is my code:
    val featureCollection = FeatureCollection.fromJsonOrNull(geoJSON)
    val layer = featureCollection?.let { FeatureCollectionLayer(it) }

    val lineSymbol = SimpleLineSymbol(SimpleLineSymbolStyle.Solid, Color.black, 1f)


    // Create a simple fill symbol with solid color
    val fillSymbol = SimpleFillSymbol(SimpleFillSymbolStyle.Solid, Color.green, lineSymbol)

    // Create a renderer using the symbol
    val simpleRenderer = SimpleRenderer(fillSymbol)

    layer?.layers?.map {
        it.forEach { item ->
            println("item visible:" + item.isVisible)
            item.renderer = simpleRenderer
        }
    }

    if (layer != null) {
        mapView.apply {
            map?.operationalLayers?.clear()
            map?.operationalLayers?.add(layer)
        }
    }

I also debug the code, what I had found was the item in the FeatureCollection is empty, I wonder if it was the problem. The doc give me little detail about it.
